# What is the axios or ajax equivalent for cURL's --form?

Tags: node.js, ajax, curl, httprequest, axios

I am creating a task to send a PUT request and upload a `.pot` file using axios in node.

I can run

```
curl -i -u api:<api-key> -F file=@dist/file.pot https://api-link.com/v2/api
```

and it'll work fine

I have tried doing this in node

```
var fd = require('form-data');
var axios = require('axios');
var form = new FormData();
form.append('file', 'dist/file.pot');
var header = { headers: Object.assign({}, apiToken(), form.getHeaders()) };

axios.put('https://api-link.com/v2/api/', form, header)
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

and this doesn't work like the curl command. `apiToken()` is a function to handle the `-u api:<api-key>` part of the curl command, and it returns `{'Authorization': 'Basic <api-key>'}`. I've checked that the function works because I am able to successfully do a get request.

So what is the equivalent of `-F file=@dist/file.pot` in ajax or axios?

Answer (score -1):

Try the below solution:

`var options = { 
   headers: Object.assign({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, apiToken(), 
            form.getHeaders()) 
};`

`axios.post('https://api-link.com/v2/api/', formData, options)`

Also check if the content-type header is being set as multipart/form-data or not.

Comment: The content type is being set, but I get a 411 status response saying that length is required??

Comment: Try something like this to get rid of the content-length issues `form.getLength(function(err,length){
    var r = request.post('http://your-site.com', { headers: { 'content-length': length } }, function(err, res, body){ console.log(body) });
     r._form = form
});`
Following the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/316)